# Echo a variable defined in a PHP script using AS2

Tags: php, actionscript, actionscript-2

let's say I have a variable in PHP and I need to echo it in AS2, how to do that?

```
<?php
$var = "variable";
?>
```

I need the ActionScript 2 code to connect to that PHP file, take the var $var and echo it.
Thanks!

Comment: I mean, how do I link it to the ActionScript?

Answer (score 0):

Just `echo` it with `&` ! You will get it inside the AS2

```
<?php
$var = "I will go inside AS2";
echo "&AS2Var=$var&";
?>
```

[`Example Link`](http://snipplr.com/view/8878/as2-loadvars-php-example/)

Comment: How do I link it to the ActionScript?

Comment: Call the PHP file from your AS3 , using `URLLoader` class.

Comment: I'm using AS2 not AS3.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example

```
var post_obj:LoadVars = new LoadVars(); 
var result_obj:LoadVars = new LoadVars(); 
// when PHP respond....
result_obj.onLoad = function(success:Boolean) { 
    if (success) { 
        trace('from PHP : ' + result_obj.fromPHP + ' / fromAS : ' + result_obj.fromAS);
    } else { 
      trace('error...');
    } 
}; 
// define some params to pass to PHP
post_obj.fromAS= "Hello from AS";   
// call PHP script, when its done, onLoad event of result_obj will trigger
post_obj.sendAndLoad("/path/to/my/script.php", result_obj);
```

script.php

```
<?php 

echo "&fromAS=PHP received : " . $_POST['fromAS'];
echo "&fromPHP=PHP did this at ".date("Y-m-d H:i:s")."&";    
?>
```

This will output in Flash

```
from PHP : PHP did this at 2013-11-26 20:47:02 / fromAS : PHP received : Hello from AS
```